# How to avoid page break inside table in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, page-break-inside

How to avoid table splitting into two pages, and if it is too long, then moving whole table to the new page? 
I tried

```
<table style="break-inside:avoid-page">
```

or wrapping the table in a div

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
```

but none of the above have any effect, the table at the bottom of the page still splits into half if it is too long. 
Please note , I am not using xsl:fo, but xsl:template

Comment: What is your definition of page, do you generate PDFs?

Comment: Yes, it is for PDFs

Comment: are you using Apache FOP?

Comment: no, Winnovative HTML to PDF Converter for .NET. Does it make difference on how the html is converted and what styles are used?